# I can't seem to figure out my div youtube placements

Tags: css, html

Ok so as you all will see I am very new to this and am really struggling to get what I want here. I would like to know how to push the youtube video down inside of that div a bit farther. Anyways I'm sure this is a simple fix that I will get reamed for but I have searched and tried to understand what I have been doing wrong but it just isn't working out. Here is what I have so far.

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>James Photo Tab</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
aside, article, section, header, footer, nav {
    display: block;
}
article, div, h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    background: url(images/grid.gif);
}
body {
    width: 520px;
    margin: auto;
    background:white;

}
.one {
    background:grey;
    width:520px;
    height:75px;
    border-radius:15px;
    position:relative;
}
.two {
    background:#0000FF;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:5px;
    top:78px;
    left:px;
}
.three {
    background: rgba(227,208,123,.6);
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:5px;
    top:78px;
    left: 424px;
}
div {
    clear: both;

}
p{  height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.three { background:#33FFFF;

}
.four { width:520px;
        height:auto;
        background:grey;
        border-radius:0px 10px 10px 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top:160px;
}
.five {width: 400px;
       height:233px;
       background:black;
       top:250px;
}

.six {width:450px;
      height:75px;
      background:#0000FF;
      top:750px;
      border-radius:15px;
      position:static;
      margin:10px;
      bottom: 10px;
}

.like {width: 200px;
        height: 45px;
        background:#33FFFF;
        border-radius: 5px; 
        position:absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
        }

.tab1 {
    width: 75px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0px 0px;
    background:grey;
    position: absolute; 
    top:115px;
    left:368px;
}
.tab2 {
    width: 75px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0px 0px;
    background:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    left: 445px;
}


/*add styles here*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<article>

    <div class="one">

        <p>
        <font size="10em" color="white">
            BANNER IMG
        </font>
        </p>
        <div class="like">
            <p>
                Like Counter
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<h1 class="two">Share!</h1>
<h1 class="three">Like!</h1>

</article>
</body>
<body>
<article> 

<h1 class="tab1"> Tab 1</h1>
<h1 class="tab2"> Tab 2</h1>

<div class="four" align="center">

<div class="five" align="center">       
        <div class="eight"><iframe width="400" height="233" top="50px" margin="40px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ErkaM9IvZ7U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>  
<div class="six" align="center" onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <p><font size="30em" color="white">Share Button</font></p>

</div>
<div class="six" align="center" onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <p><font size="30em" color="white">Share Button</font></p>

</div>
</div>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you want it to look like? I can't clearly visualise your text requirements. Also, how is it 'not working out?'

Comment: Yeah sorry I am trying to make a facebook fan page and wanted to copy this kind of a look here on the risk factions page. http://www.facebook.com/riskfactions

Comment: I think I am just having trouble figuring out how to write my code so certain things stay within the sections I want them to. I would really like to have the Banner, like counter and the share, like buttons all in something like a main header div and then the rest in a body div? would that work? and how would I accomplish something like that?

Comment: Oh and thank you very much for trying to help me. Like I said im new to all of this and really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some top margin to the div containing the youtube video would move it down. Not sure how far you wanted it but you can play around with the pixels.

```
.eight{
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: haha wow... like I said I would look foolish but even though this works well to create space above the video why does it seem to push right a little bit? Thank you very much though!

Comment: Hard to say without looking at it directly, but just a thought - you might try removing the div called 'eight' and adding the top margin to the rules for 'five'. That eight div isn't necessary and it's always best to keep things simple.

Edit - if you feel that I answered your question, can you click the checkbox next to my answer? Thanks!